# Authenticate with a 3rd party website from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, oauth-2.0

what I need to achieve is the following but am quite stuck on the correct way to go about this:

1. From WordPress, specifically in the admin console I need to authenticate with an external website in a secure manner
2. Store a token of some sort (oauth2?)
3. Make authenticated call form my plugin to the 3rd party rest api

What would be the best way and a couple of methods to:

1. Authenticate, retrieve store a token from wordpress admin (preferably Oauth2)
2. send this token to the external site with every api call?

Apologies on the vague nature but any direction will really help!!!